# Extracting metadata from Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, image, metadata

How do I extract metadata from Google Earth?

I downloaded the satellite image from Google Earth Pro.

The data I want to know is that the date, resolution, and the server from which the image was taken (as far as I know, there are Google Earth servers around the world, and the resolution provided by each server varies. Therefore, I would like to know which server the image I downloaded is from.)

I would like to know how to get the data for these images.

Comment: Do you have gdal installed?  If so, open a command prompt in the directory that stores your data and run gdalinfo yourfilenamehere.  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html

Comment: gdalinfo will not help you here.  If you "export" a satellite image from Earth Pro, it is effectively just a JPG or PNG screenshot of the data shown in Google Earth, and will not contain any of the metadata tags that an original satellite imagery source file would contain.  (@GBG, let me know if I mis-understood your suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

Google does not provide "metadata" for the many images that get combined into its satellite view mosaics. But in Google Earth Pro, using a combination of the historical imagery tool, the image date reported in the status bar, and the copyright strings, you can usually figure out the date and provider of many images.  That said, if the imagery is very high res (like the 15cm imagery in many cities), then it's probably aerial imagery, which is mosaiced from many photos over many dates, and does not provide useful imagery dates.  To reduce the amount of that data shown, use the Historical Imagery tool, and turn off the "3D buildings" layer.